# How to replace string abc to 'a','b','c' with regex

Tags: regex

I need some help to replace string in this format `abc` to `'a','b','c'`

I used [this](https://regex101.com/r/vF1eR6/1) regex `/((?<=.)(?!$))/gm` to transform `abc` to `a,b,c` but lack quotes.

Comment: Which implementation/host of regexp are you using? What have you tried? And what contexts should this cover? Just one string? Just 3 letters? Or should this be a substitution that can apply to any length of string?

Comment: @LT001 what language? Javascript ... java ? Use the adequate tags :)

Comment: Is one string, but can be one or more letters

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oN9wV2/2

Comment: So you want to just put quotes around each letter in the string?  There is absolutely no reason to use a regex for this (despite multiple answers already proposing a regex).  Just get one character of the string at a time...using whatever facility is available in the language you are using.

Comment: @npinti, i try https://regex101.com/r/vF1eR6/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*JS code*

```js
var re = /([a-z])/g; 
var str = 'abcaabcdef';
var subst = '\'$1\','; 
 
var result = str.replace(re, subst)
result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
document.write(result);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Du6FE4)**

Comment: I don´t try it, because i want use regex replace.

Comment: @LT001 i didn't got you.. can you explain??

Comment: your solution works but puts quotation mark at the end. ex; 'a','b','c','a','a','b','c','d','e','f',.

Comment: @LT001 run the code here..It is removing the last comma

Comment: Ok a see you remove comma using document.write(result.substring(0, result.length - 1)), in case case i need other solution to remove.

Comment: @LT001 this is the best you can do(and most efficient) till I know..because there are two different replacement needed which will require two different regex..if you want I can write it for you

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution for n letters :

Apply the following two search/replace :

```
search [a-z](?!$)
replace by '\0',

search [a-z]$
replace by '\0'
```

---

Specific solution for 3 letters :

```
search ([a-z])([a-z])([a-z])
replace by '\1','\2','\3'
```

This is language-agnostic regex and should work in any language, although you might have to escape some characters differently.

Comment: I don´t know the length of the string. Your solution supose I have length 3.

Comment: Well duh ! You didn't specify anything in your question, I had to make a few assumptions. That's point 2 of my list there. I'll make a generic solution soon, but you'd better edit your question.